# MNCs income greater than origin GDP

Tags: gdp, multinational-companies

Can anyone explain why the net income of some MNCs *overwhelmingly surpass* the GDP of countries/regions, where their sources of labor/raw materials are located? Accompanying references are welcome.

P.S. :- My academic training is in history, and am not really familiar with nitty-gritty aspects of economics. Apologies, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: How do you define *overwhelmingly*? Also most companies nowadays use sources from all over the world, for example Apple will have design in California but manufacturing in China and utilize labor of distributors in all countries it’s present... There are no stupid questions, and in this case I can see even some interesting question being at the core but as you are asking it it’s simply not answerable you need to provide some details and clarity and also decide how do you want to assign MMC to particular geographical area - doing so based on narrow use of resources/labor is not very fortunate

Comment: Some specific examples might help this question a lot.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment. For example, you can have a hypothetical software developer that draws let’s say 70\% of their labor from Luxembourg has relatively small team and makes software that millions of people use which could easily make the firm having higher income than GDP of Luxembourg but does it even make sense to compare the firms income to the income of Luxembourg when the MNC supplies global market of millions or even billions of people while Luxembourg manages a acountry that’s size of flyover town in US?

Comment: @1muflon1 excuse me, i think my response answers to both the surface level of the question, and the interesting one. Your comment was not there when I posted it however

Comment: @the_rainbox you don’t need to excuse yourself I think that given the question your answer is good one I just gave you plus one but I wanted to give OP feedback because the question as it is now is poor fit for the SE model and also in general outside SE it would be question that’s framed in a way that would rather obscure than illuminate due to the problems of even assigning MNC some geographic location that the question glosses over

Comment: Excusing myself is purely a matter of hierarchy for me, in which I strongly believe. Also, I had to defend my self against possible attacks concerning plagiarism, somehow. Thank you, and good evening

Comment: @1muflon1 Your politeness (or desire to avoid confrontation) clouds your judgement.

Comment: @Giskard I suppose you are right because this was already  pointed to me once before but could you be more specific so I can better myself for the future? Did I go too easy on the_rainbox or OP or both?

Comment: @1muflon1 I can only speak for myself, but I don't understand the core of the question, and I find that the answer makes unconnected unsourced claims.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer I could give is this; *they have more revenue and less costs*.

A multinational company, has branches all over the Earth and utilizes these and their resources to their fullest extend, with utmost efficiency.

Kindly note how a company is much easier to run than a nation, with regards to uncertainty, risk - danger and of course, budget management.

On the politics side of things, which is arguably less naive;

It is a structuralist theory that MNCs are a tool of developed nations that sucks the life force out of developing nations (by obtaining their resources and bringing profits with them), therefore there is also a relation of causality, between the great net income of an MNC and the lower GDP of such nations.

With this theory, I have to say, I'm fairly skeptical.

If you'd like to read on the *politics* of such matters, I'd suggest Theodore Cohn's "*Global Political Economy: Theory and Practice*". In fact, any Political Economy textbook that dwells on the global economy will probably contain a chapter or two concerning multinational companies.